# Javascript 'likes' and 'template' keyword

Tags: javascript

I see the following Javascript code, and don't know the meaning of 'likes' and 'template' keyword there, have tried googling, but can't find anything useful.
Anyone know what are they?

```
var data = {
    likes: [
      {
        'a':1,
        'b':2
      }
    ]
};
var html = template('likes', data);
$(".somediv").append(html);
```

Comment: It only means something to the person who wrote it.There is no universal definition.

Comment: `likes` is just a self-defined property name inside a JavaScript object, no keyword. Same for template, that references a function defined earlier. Both are *no* keywords in JavaScript.

Comment: They aren't keywords. `likes` is a property name on the object and `template` is the name of a function.

Answer (score 1):

Neither are keywords. `likes` is an arbitrary field name; without any context it might as well be `tacos`.

`template` is the name of a user-defined function from somewhere other than this snippet.